# API keys and google map V2 status

Tags: google-api

I have two questions.
Firstly, when will support for google maps api v2 end, how long will I still be able to use it as v3 is out. Secondly, with the free direction api you can only make 2500 requests perday, is this for each device with my app or for my app? If two people use my app will that 2500 count for both of them or is it per device?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be addressed to technical support.

Comment: I was on the Google developer console and it says that any question regarding API's must be addressed to the correct community. I couldn't find any technical support email...Can you supply me one please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Seems like you should switch to API v3 immediately - [deprecation warning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3)
2. As [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#basics) says, server side access is per your account, while client side access (from the browser) is per user, so it scales with increasing number of your website users.

Comment: Okay thank you, just one more question about the quotas then. I am switching to v3 of google maps api now and there is a limit on it as well, i.e. 25000 requests per day. If I understand correctly the direction api and maps api quotas is only applicable per client, so for instance I have my app and two people are using it, will the quota them scale to 50000 for maps and 5000 for direction api, or will they share the quota? That is all I am still unsure about.